# ember liquid-teather modals - set routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have setup my modals, and am using liquid-teather.

I have 2 different modals on my page - summer-recipe.hbs:
1 x salads modal
1 x smoothies modal

Both work.

As both modals are on, and open from the summer-recipe.hbs page. The route file would be routes/summer-recipes.js

Is there a way to set a specific route up for each modal. Basically I'd like to be able to set up/have the equivalent to:

routes/salads.js
routes/smoothies.js

Snippets of code for one modal below:

**summer-recipes.hbs:**

```
{{#if showSaladsDialog}}
{{#liquid-tether
to="modal-dialog"
target="document.body"
targetModifier="visible"
attachment="middle center"
tetherClass="modal-dialog"
overlayClass="modal-backdrop"}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Salads</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            Salads content...
                        </div><!-- /.right col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-close" {{action "closeSaladsModalDialog"}}> Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/liquid-tether}}
{{/if}}
```

**controllers/summer-recipes.js:**

```
  showSaladsDialog: gte('newUser', 1),

  actions: {
    openSaladsModalDialog() {
      this.set('editUser', 1);
    },

    closeSaladsModalDialog() {
      this.set('editUser', 0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can, just define same route for salads as you defined for summer-recipe.

Comment: I don't understand. I need the modal to open with certain info depending on the route. E.g. if someone was to open a 'addNewSalad' modal there would be a form with blank fields.

Comment: But if there open a 'editSalad' modal the field would have data in there of the salad they were editing. Then there would also be a modal to just view the salad info 'viewSalad'.

Comment: Ok, you need to define url for salads in router.js, then you have to create Route for salads and in that route use model hook to get neccessery data.

Comment: Right. I have now defined 'salads' in route.js: this.route('salads'). I have created a routes/salads.js file. have used the model hook to get necessary data. but can only use one model hook. so how do i tell it to do open a modal with blank form fields in (when 'addSalad' is clicked), but open a form with data in the fields when 'editSalad' is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define url for salads in router.js, create Route for it and use model hook in your Route to collect necessary data. Since you want to create and edit salads you should create separate routes for that also.

```
this.route('salads', function() {
  this.route('new');
  this.route('edit', { path: '/salads/:salad_id' });
});
```

Now in Routes for them use model hook to createRecord(for new Route) or findRecord by salad_id from params(for edit Route).